# Do any of the computer programs used in 1980s Doctor Who still exist?

Tags: effects, doctor-who

In the 1980s, the Doctor's TARDIS had three computer terminals in the console. Two of them had real monitors and the third (in the rare shot that showed it) was just a plastic box with a flat covering (not a curved CRT screen).

Sometimes, they would show the code running on these computers (BBC Micros) for a fraction of a second before the computer program started. Some other "futuristic" computers were shown, running the same (real-world) language.

If you pause an episode, you can see the final few lines of some of these programs, but never the whole code. Do any of these programs still exist in full?

This is a follow-up question from https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/what-computer-system-is-this-from-1984-doctor-who which has some more screen-shots!

[image: TARDIS console running BBC Micro program]
[image: TARDIS program output]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It's quite frequent to pull such code from a text book or other programming book. But without seeing the code, it will be hard to say.

Comment: Are you asking if the code is real,  or functional?

Comment: @cde The code is both real and functional. You see the code running and the output in the actual episodes.

Comment: Looks like simple cnc type code. Start position, move n steps.

Comment: @cde I know what it is, I want to know if any of it was kept.

Comment: Very cool! Yeah, it's definitely BASIC and it's drawing the circle and grid you see in the bottom shot. I guess you'd have to find someone from the BBC to know whether it's still around anywhere. Good question! Unfortunately, I don't have an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about locating computer programs.

Comment: Questions about the current location of props appear to be on-topic. I don't see how this is materially different.